# how to chnge username and password of rhel instance of gcp

Tags: passwords

I created a vm instance of rhel image on gcp but the username is showing my email and i didn't set the password for the user but i want to change the both username and password anyone can help me out with this issue? I set the root password with the sudo passwd command which directly ask new password but for the user i try to change the password that is asking for current password while i didn't set password i directly login with ssh in open browser option.

passwd
asking current password that i don't know
i also try to delete user that also didn't succeed